# Deployment failure from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

Deploying a solution from visual studio 2010 to sharepoint foundation.  The first time i deploy i get an error:

Error   10  Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Feature 'c6c0e10a-3212-48dc-a2c3-6286e323d558' is not activated at this scope.
        0   0   MarelSite

However if i deploy again everything is fine.  Any ideas why it fails the first time and succeeds the second?

***EDIT:*** The solution i have has two features one of which is dependent on the other.  I was playing around and apparently this is being caused by the Feature Activation Dependency that i added between Feature 2 and Feature 1.  When i remove it the problem goes away.  Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

While Retracting the feature, there might be a feature deactivating event trying to delete or remove something that is already referenced by the site.

For example, if its trying to remove the master page, that is already set to the site, then you might get this error initially. The next time when it retracts, since the references are replaced, the master page gets deleted. Something like that. The best option would be to check your feature deactivating event or launch a debugger on the code to find the exact culprit.

Good Luck ...

Comment: When playing around i discovered this is being cause by a Feature Activation Dependency.  When i remove it ...the error stops.  Any ideas with this update?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like either your dependency is set up backward or you are activating your Features in the wrong order.